# NMaximize and Accuracy

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem with NMaximize which is best depicted by the following figure. The result indicates, that the solution mathematica finds seems to be smooth except a few outliers. How can I get rid of them? I tried to change the method NMaximizes uses, e.g. SimulatedAnnealing etc. but it did not improve. Moreover, changing WorkingPrecision was also not a viable option, too (increase up to 400). Any kind of help is appreciated!

[image: Solution of NMaximze]

The code is as follows:

```
RS[a_, p_, v_, t1_, T1_, x0_, i1_, i2_, t2_]:=Module[{z, T0, dT0, b, n1, d, i},  
b := 1/2 - (a/v^2) + Sqrt[(1/2 - a/v^2)^2 + (2*p)/v^2];   
n1[w_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], w];  
z[a1_] := a1/(p-a);  
i[a4_] := i1 + a4*i2;  
T0[a2_, a3_] := T1 + (a2)^t1*(a3)^t2;  
dT0[a2_, a3_] := t1*(a2)^(t1-1)*(a3)^t2;  
d[a2_, a1_, a3_, a5_] := (Log[T0[a2, a3] - Log[a5]] + (a - 1/2*(v)^2)*a3)*(v*Sqrt[a3])^(-1);  
NMaximize[{((T0[a2, a3]-1)*z[a1]-a2-i[a4])*(x0/a1)^b, 
a4*Exp[-p*a3]*n1[d[a2, a1, a3, a5]]*1/(v*Sqrt[a3])*dT0[a2, a3]==1 
&& a1 >= 0 && a2 >= 0 && a3 >= 0 && a4 >= 0 && a5 >= 1}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}] 
]
```

while the graph is generated using, e.g.:

```
Plot[RS[0.03, 0.05, j, 0.1, 1.1, 1, 30, 0.1, 0.025][[2, 1, 2]], {j, 0.05, 0.25}]
```

Comment: It will be easier if You provide input data instead of plot image.

Comment: Luke, without code to reproduce the problem this question will most likely be closed - so please add that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, for certain values of `v`, (the automatic method/options of) `NMaximize` fail(s) because the objective function becomes too complicated. In addition, your constraints are not set properly. For example, you allow $a_1$ and $a_3$ to be equal to $0$ even though they appear as part of denominators. (The outliers seem to be generated with `NMaximize` getting trapped at $a_3=0$ - the actual value of $a_1$ is irrelevant in that case.)

I tried changing the method and (one of) its parameters (`Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.1}`), as well as the inequality constraints of $a_1$ and $a_3$ to `a1 > 0` and `a3 > 0.001`, respectively (`a3>0` still gave me solutions with $a_3=0$).

Replacing the `NMaximize` function in your module with

```
NMaximize[{((T0[a2, a3] - 1)*z[a1] - a2 - i[a4])*(x0/a1)^b, 
  a4*Exp[-p*a3]*n1[d[a2, a1, a3, a5]]*1/(v*Sqrt[a3])*dT0[a2, a3] == 
    1 && a1 > 0 && a2 >= 0 && a3 > 0.001 && a4 >= 0 && a5 >= 1}, {a1, 
  a2, a3, a4, a5}, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.1}]
```

and performing the optimization for a limited set of values of `v` (`Range[0.05, 0.3, 0.01]`) gives a smooth solution

```
c = Monitor[
  Table[RS[0.03, 0.05, j, 0.1, 1.1, 1, 30, 0.1, 0.025][[2, 1, 2]], {j,
     Range[0.05, 0.3, 0.01]}], j];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[0.05, 0.3, 0.01], c}]]
```

[image]

It is very much possible to get outliers for a denser set of values of `v` (e.g., those evaluated by `Plot`). In that case, I would try different methods/parameters for these specific values of `v`. However, if plotting is all you care about, the above graph looks fine to me.

P.S. Detailed description of methods and parameters used by `NMaximize` can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#434989722)

Comment: The Mathematica documentation on NMaximize is lengthy.   I don't really want to invest time in the theory of maximization; I just want to use it.  Unfortunately, the Mathematica documentation doesn't  seem to answer the most basic question:  I just want to know if a larger ScalingFactor means that Mathematic will work harder and longer to get my results.  I'm assuming that the more time Mathematica spends on a maximization, the more accurate the result will be.    Maybe I'm oversimplifying the subject, but nonetheless I'd be thankful if you could help me with an answer.